# referencing ints from other classes

Tags: java, android

If I wanted to reference an int from another class how would I go about doing that?

```
public class Zoom extends View {
    private Drawable image;
    public int zoomControler = 20;

    public Zoom(Context context) {
        super(context);
        image=context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);
        setFocusable(true);      
    }

    @Override            
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        image.setBounds((getWidth ()/2)-zoomControler,
                        (getHeight()/2)-zoomControler,
                        (getWidth ()/2)+zoomControler,
                        (getHeight()/2)+zoomControler);
        image.draw(canvas);
    }
}

class HelloOnTouchListener implements OnTouchListener{
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

In this case I want to reference the `zoomControler` from the first class in the second `HelloOnTouchListener` class.

Comment: You should really put some effort into formatting your code. Consistent indentation and spacing makes code *so* much more readable. Spelling mistakes in code are irksome as well: it's "controller" with two L's.

Comment: i know how to spell controller i changed so i would not get zoomcontrols mixed up with it as for the indentations i dont know how to post code on this site...my code looks much nicer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create a getter in the first class something like.

```
public int getZoomController()
{
    return zoomController;
}
```

And in your listener it would be.

```
((Zoom) arg0).getZoomController();
```

Answer (score 1):

While @jsmith's answer is the recommended approach, the fact that the `zoomControler` (sic) attribute is public means that you can also do this:

```
int z = ((Zoom) arg0).zoomControler;
```

or even

```
((Zoom) arg0).zoomControler = z;
```

However, accessing attributes like this is bad style, and even exposing the attributes is bad style.  You should probably change `zoomControler` to `private` so that other classes *have to* access it via getters and setters.